# Can't start Ruby Sinatra App as systemd unit - gem not found

Tags: ruby, centos, rubygems, rvm, systemd

I'm trying to start Sinatra application as Systemd unit.
It's not a first time, this service was working before, but now I'm stuck.

`systemctl start service` always throws cannot find gem sinatra

Here is the log:

```
Nov 27 19:52:45 cloud.onehostcloud.hosting ruby[29074]: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7-devel/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
Nov 27 19:52:45 cloud.onehostcloud.hosting ruby[29074]: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7-devel/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
Nov 27 19:52:45 cloud.onehostcloud.hosting ruby[29074]: from /usr/lib/app/server.rb:34:in `<main>'
Nov 27 19:52:45 cloud.onehostcloud.hosting systemd[1]: app.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

The app.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=API Server Service

[Service]
Type=simple
Group=appuser
User=appuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/app/server.rb
StartLimitInterval=30
StartLimitBurst=3
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've checked and the `$:` is correct, so if I try with the same path all gems can be found and included via `irb`

Using CentOS 7 with RVM Ruby 2.5.7

Thank you!

Comment: Your environment isn't loading rvm, which is where your rubies and gems seem to be.

Comment: What could be the solution, to make systemd load rvm env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference to `/usr/bin/ruby` is bypassing RVM, and it sounds like you are using RVM to manage your gems.

RVM doesn't seem to have documentation on how to set up `systemd` services, but it does [have guidance on launching scripts from `cron`](https://rvm.io/integration/cron), which is a similar situation.

Basically, RVM provides a wrapper for each combination of ruby version and gemset, which you can use in your `app.service` file.  Your `ExecService` line would look something like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/appuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-3.0.0@appgemset/ruby /usr/lib/app/server.rb
```

If you haven't created a specific gemset for your app, then you can omit the `@appgemset` part, and only specify the ruby version you want to use.